# Xpath selecionar que el campo tiene mas de un atributo

Tags: java, xml, selenium, xpath

Hola Muy buenas Tengo un problema a la hora de buscar otro atributo en un nodo
[image: aquí esta el xml]

WebElement SelecionFechaCalendario = findElementByXPath("//tbody/tr/td[@data-month="+fechaselecionarmes+"]/a[@date="+fechanueva+"]",DEFAULT_WAIT_TIME,false);

tengo este parte del código y tengo que comprobar si en la fecha seccionada también esta el elemento precio y sino pasar un dia mas y buscar el siguiente día alguna idea alguien e como comprobar que tiene el otro elemento también. gracias.

Comment: Por favor añade mas informacion. Llegas a obtener el objeto 'a' del que quieres obtener los parámetros? que valores tienen las variables fechaselecionarmes y fechanueva? entiendo que eso es un ejemplo de estructura de html que se repite. Tienes alguna URL a la que podamos acceder para comprobar el codigo? gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta es: [@class='xxxxxx' and @id='xxxxx'] asi se pueden consultar varios atributos desde xpath.